# Django View : Either save(update) all objects or None of them

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a view which basically handles a transaction. In that view, I have to save(update) multiple objects such that either all of them get updated or None of them gets updated. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please add your code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `transaction` from `django.db`

```
from django.db import transaction

def myview(request):
    #Some Code
    with transaction.atomic():
             a.save()
             b.save()
             c.save()
```

All the updates inside the with block are executed as a single transaction

Comment: Im curious... wouldn't this just delay the issue? if `b` would fail to save then wouldn't `a` have already saved? (I thought `atomic` just meant one call to the db but it still does the same (optimised) queries)

Comment: @Sayse: I don't think so. Atomocity is a property that though the statements are executed, they are not COMMITTED to the database. In transactions, if any statement causes an error, a ROLLBACK happens, making sure none of the changes are updated to the database in that transaction.

Comment: @Sayse: For further clarifications, see how the database works, and learn about commit, rollback, savepoint statements

Comment: Ah ok, yes that makes sense I'd forgotten about the rollback part of atomic but it does sound familiar :)

Comment: @AswinMurugesh : Should it be `while transaction.atomic()` or `with transaction.atomic()`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly

Comment: @anon: Sorry. My mistake :P